# Modifying a context menu for the editable combobox (WPF)

Tags: wpf, combobox, contextmenu

I have a requirement to modify the built-in combo-box context menu (Copy, cut, paste) by adding icon images to the menu items.

I added the desired context menu to PART_EditableTextBox inside ComboBox control template and included the template as a resource.

```
 <TextBox x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox"
               Style="{x:Null}"
               Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxTextBox}"
               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
               VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
               Margin="3,3,23,3"
               Focusable="True"
               Background="Transparent"
               Visibility="Hidden"
               IsReadOnly="{TemplateBinding IsReadOnly}">
                        <TextBox.ContextMenu>
                            <ContextMenu>
                                <MenuItem Header="Copy"
                                          Command="ApplicationCommands.Copy">
                                    <MenuItem.Icon>
                                        <Image Source="pack://application:,,,/testApp.UI;component/ViewModels/PngImages/Copy.ico" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=ImageStyleSmall}" />
                                    </MenuItem.Icon>
                                </MenuItem>
                                <MenuItem Header="Cut"
                                          Command="ApplicationCommands.Cut">
                                    <MenuItem.Icon>
                                        <Image Source="pack://application:,,,/testApp.UI;component/ViewModels/PngImages/Cut.ico" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=ImageStyleSmall}" />
                                    </MenuItem.Icon>
                                </MenuItem>
                                <MenuItem Header="Paste"
                                          Command="ApplicationCommands.Paste">
                                    <MenuItem.Icon>
                                        <Image Source="pack://application:,,,testApp.UI;component/ViewModels/PngImages/Paste.ico" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=ImageStyleSmall}" />
                                    </MenuItem.Icon>
                                </MenuItem>
                            </ContextMenu>
                        </TextBox.ContextMenu>
                    </TextBox>
```

When the application runs, the context menu works as planned, but the side effect is that my combo box has lost a border.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my original test project I used the control template which I copied from the MSDN site (at learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/…). Then I took a different approach: created a small app, added combo box and selected Edit template option. Made similar changes to that template and got it to work. I have both the context menu working and combo box border intact.

Answer (score 0):

What about your Template "ComboBoxTextBox"? Do you have a border there?

Comment: I haven't modified that template, nor any other. ComboBoxTextBox  template has a border element.

Answer (score 0):

Below is how the beginning portion of the default TextBox's style is declared:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource TextBox.Static.Border}"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation" Value="None"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
    <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="VerticalFirst"/>
    <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False"/>
```

By saying Style="{x:Null}" , you basically tell the framework "I don't want any of that!"

Notice these 2 lines you are lacking:

```
<Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource TextBox.Static.Border}"/>
<Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
```

The other missing properties will probably break some tab navigation, interaction with devices, drag & drop, etc. as well

Comment: I followed the suggestion but it didn't help.